# Google maps wont show markers with remote images in closeups

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

Google maps since API 3.10 wont show markers with remote images in closeups. Meaning when i zoom in, I can't see images. When I zoomout I can see either part of image or a full image if I zoom out completely.

Though if marker image is local file, it is displayed every time.

See samples:

1. [Closeup](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10867328/scr/Screenshot_2012-11-30-12-36-18.png). Only local file markers are seen
2. [Zoom out](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10867328/scr/Screenshot_2012-11-30-12-36-01.png). Part of image is seen
3. [Zoom more](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10867328/scr/Screenshot_2012-11-30-12-36-39.png). All image is seen, but a weird vertical line appears

Map is launched from withing phonegap application.

Code for both local & remote image marker is pretty the same:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(location.image,
            new google.maps.Size(120, 120),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(iconSize*14/32, iconSize*40/32),
            new google.maps.Size(iconSize*1, iconSize*1)
        ); //REMOTE IMAGE

var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/marker-big-'+location.status+'.png',
            //LOCAL IMAGE
            new google.maps.Size(96, 111),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(iconSize*16/32-1, iconSize*42/32),
            new google.maps.Size(iconSize*36/32, iconSize*42/32));

localMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude),
            title:location.text,
            map: map,
            icon: shadow,
            zIndex: index*2
        });

remoteMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude),
            title:location.text,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            zIndex: index*2+1
        });
```

OLD API 3.9 works fine

Comment: You wrote "API 3.9 works fine".  Create an issue on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) with an example (jsfiddle, live link or attach the files required to reproduce the problem; photos do not help).

Comment: I've fired an issue, noone ever replied. Here is a [zip](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10867328/bg.html.zip) with isolated problem. When changed from 3.10 to 3.9 in code - works fine. if not - problem as shown on screenshots

Comment: [google issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4616)

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with scaling icons.  Try it with unscaled icons.

Comment: I need scaled icons to support retina properly. Besides both local & remote images are scaled.

Comment: Did you had any success then downgrading to version 3.9? Having same issues here... Using Phonegap... Needing retina resolution and remote images. Can you help us to get it working? The google issue says, that it is fixed, but it still occurs in the current released version. I already added a comment to the issue.